# laravel user dashboard in react adminpanel in blade keeping DRY for controllers

Tags: php, laravel

In my project, we are making API's endpoints in Laravel for react app and admin panel in blades only.

So I had to create separate controller in API folder as endpoints for react app and another controller to render blade view for admin for the same table (say messages).

But I do not want to repeat code like common checks and condition I want to keep these things somewhere commonplace so I can use it in both API endpoints and admin controllers.

Can someone share the reference for the best approach or some ideas.

Comment: I think this is opinion based: I personally opt to move common checks in [form requests](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/validation#form-request-validation). Utility functions usually go in a separate utility class and blade markup goes in [components](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/blade#components-and-slots) where it makes sense, otherwise in files that can just be included.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. and I resolved by using the Service Layer. This [link](https://m.dotdev.co/design-pattern-service-layer-with-laravel-5-740ff0a7b65f) may help you to understand in detail about service.

In simple words, service can be injected into your controller. Service will get a request from the controller with inputs(which could be an array) and can send you back response(Which could be boolean or object).

Service also can help with test cases.

Good Luck.